# How can I set the default build target to x86 for all projects, in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, x86

Is there is a way to set the default build action to x86, instead of Any CPU in Visual Studio 2008?

That way all new projects will be compiled for x86, and great features like edit and continue will work.

Perhaps a registry hack or somthing simple, like a global option.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could edit the project templates with, say, Notepad.  They are located in `Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates(Cache)\CSharp\Windows\xxxx\*.zip`.  Edit the .csproj file in the .zip archive and add

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

to the Debug and/or Release PropertyGroup.

Or consider upgrading to VS2010, x86 is now the default.

Comment: Thanks. I have upgraded to 2010, but still need to work on some 2008 projects, without converting the project file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not that simple, but I start all my projects from a template; the template imports a default project like

```
<Import Project="..\template\defaults.csproj" />
```

and there the default platform is set to x86 (there is even no Any CPU):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
  <!--goes on setting outputpath, default build options, ...-->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Upon loading a newly created project from this template, VS automatically takes Debug|x86 as config.

Comment: In doing this, do you have to provide a project template for every project type?

Comment: what do you mean with project type?
The template csproj is only 15 lines or so, it's just one <PropertyGroup> for the Guids, AssmblyName, OutputType and Versions, and the <Import> line I showed above. I guess this is all you need for any C# project?

Comment: the only difference between a WinForms and WPF for example, are the included references. The structure of the project file is the same.